# Updating more than one MongoDB document in NodeJS doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I know this question has been asked many times but I've looked it up for over 30 minutes and I honestly can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I want to update my mongo data

Here's an example of two documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561e34c68b7639481c38ce62"),
    "id" : "1657999143",
    "timeTakenAt" : 1444820166833.0000000000000000,
    "userName" : "a",
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561e34c68b7639481c38ce63"),
    "id" : "1659143",
    "timeTakenAt" : 1444820166833.0000000000000000,
    "userName" : "b",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to change to usernames to something else.

For example to JOHN CENA.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
...
var UserModel = mongoose.model('userSchema', userSchema);
...

updateUsers()

function updateUsers(){
    UserModel.update({}, {$set: {userName: 'JOHN CENA'}}, {multi:true})
}
```

But it doesn't work, not even a single document is changed.
I've also found that some people used

```
UserModel.update({}, {$set: {userName: 'JOHN CENA'}}, false,true)
```

But that one gives me an error, so I guess it's code from an older version.

However, if I use

```
UserModel.update({}, {$set: {userName: 'JOHN CENA'}},  {multi:true}, updateUsers)
```

(Which obviously loops forever since it calls itself). Every single document ends up being updated with the JOHN CENA user name.

I don't understand what's going on here, can anybody help me please ?

EDIT : In the comments below a user suggested adding an empty callback. Which I did and now it works as intended. My thanks go to him (@Sergio Tulentsev) and I hope this thread will help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Indeed, this should have worked. What are the versions you use (mongodb, node.js, mongoose)?

Comment: What if you provide an empty callback (although, this should be the problem)?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev I've downloaded the three of these 3 weeks ago. So I'm pretty sure I have the latest version of all of them. 

EDIT : So I just added an empty callback and now it works for some reason. Well my problem is solved now, thank you !

Comment: I believe so, but let's be precise here. :)

Comment: Maybe mongoose just doesn't bother sending the update to the database in absence of callback. Why do the work if nobody's watching :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the docs for [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update), if you don't want to provide a callback, you need to call `exec` on the returned `Query` to execute it:

> To update documents without waiting for a response from MongoDB, do
>   not pass a callback, then call `exec` on the returned Query

So either chain an `exec` call on your `update` or provide a callback:

```
function updateUsers(){
    UserModel.update({}, {$set: {userName: 'JOHN CENA'}}, {multi:true}).exec();
}
```

OR

```
function updateUsers(){
    UserModel.update({}, {$set: {userName: 'JOHN CENA'}}, {multi:true},
        function(err, numAffected) {...});
}
```